# Is it possible to use an external audio source?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-streaming

What I mean is, instead of playing an audio clip in the audio source in Unity3D, can I play whatever music is playing from another software and place that in the world with 3D sound.

I am using music to guide the player somewhere, but rather than having one song that I hardcode in, I would like to use the music or sound the player already listens to before starting the game. I must be able to change the volume and balance as the sound is suposed to come form somewhere in the 3D world

Comment: This question is old - does the app that you're thinking about provide it's audio to the OS?  I'm thinking most apps nowadays want their output to go directly to the speakers, like Spotify, iTunes, etc.  If you do have an app that lets you hook into the audio, then yes, all you would need to do is use a file in between that app and Unity's media player, or a plugin to stream the audio into a buffer in a plugin in Unity.